# Xcode 9 won't autocomplete functions by variable names

Tags: ios, xcode, autocomplete, xcode9-beta, xcode9

We all know and love the autocomplete feature of Xcode. 
[image]
The above screenshot is taken from Xcode 9. I looks identical to what it did in Xcode 8. It knows about my class, and all of its different declarations and functions etc. This is not a SearchPaths-problem.

In **Xcode 8**, we were able to start typing the function name or the name of any variable used in the declaration of any function/initialiser to help the autocomplete single out which we want, like this:
[image]

However, in **Xcode 9** this no longer happens. Instead, it completely ignores context and starts to show autocompletion as if I was typing this on a new line.
[image]
Is there a way to enable this again? I didn't know I needed this function until I lost it.

Comment: clean the build, force quit xcode, and open it again. does this solve your problem?

Comment: @MohammadBashirSidani Nope. I have also tried deleting derived data. It has been like this since Beta 1. Both my Xcode and my Mac has been restarted several times since the first time I noticed this.

Comment: Wait, this isn't happening to you?

Comment: I have this problem even in XCode 8 whenever I add a new class to my project. I need to close and force quit for the autocomplete to work correctly in this class.

Comment: but the wierd part of this problem, is that it only happens in swift with me. I think I'm the only one facing htis on XCode 8

Comment: works for me on Xcode8 but doesn't work on Xcode9 :(

Comment: This is so annoying, especially as Swift functions can get quite complex and the autocomplete-list isn't sorted very well.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me in XCode 9.3, but only (it seems) if all the following conditions are met:

1. The instance is created from a different file or scope than the type definition
2. The instance is *not* created from within a function
3. An instance of the same type has not already been created at the current scope. (As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35102087/2652785).)

This implies some possible workarounds. You can create the instance within a function and then move the line of code elsewhere. Or you can create a dummy instance first, followed by the real instance on the next line—this works even if you don't include the arguments on the dummy line. For example:

```
let dummy = MyObject  // no autocomplete available here
let obj = MyObject(anything: Any Object)  // autocomplete working on this line!
```