# Xcode 10 Struct Initializer autoComplete not showing

Tags: swift, xcode, struct, xcode10

I am defining my viewModels in a separate files as `struct`s,  when i am trying to create an instance of this `struct` in another file the autocomplete of the memberwise initializer is not showing..

This problem wasn't before(i.e Xcode 9) is it a bug in Xcode 10?

I have seen similar questions like [Xcode does not autocomplete memberwise initializer of a Struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35101704/xcode-does-not-autocomplete-memberwise-initializer-of-a-struct)

but it's old and the problem was in Xcode 7 or 8 maybe.

However if i place my `struct` in the file i am attempting to use it, the autocomplete will be shown, so what's the problem ?

I Also tried `.init` after the `struct` name with no luck.

Here's my ViewModels :

```
struct ProfileModels {

    struct ViewModels {


        struct profile{
            let name : URL?
            let positionAndCountry : String?
            let briefDescription : String?
            let hotelInfo : HotelInfo?

        }

        struct HotelInfo{
            let hotelName : String?
            let roomClasification : String?
            let checkInDate : String?
            let checkOutDate : String?
            let isCheckInEarly : String?
            let isCheckInLate : String?
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

**Update:**

As mentioned in the comments that it works fine if the init method called, however sometimes the autocomplete isn't showing with calling the init method...

Anyway for anybody who wants a quick workaround until this bug solved is to use the following:

- Create an **empty** struct (don't worry about the error for now)

  *example :* `ProfileModels.viewModels.profile()`
- In a new line, call the struct and the autocomplete will be shown!, now you can delete the first one.

I don't know why this happened but maybe the compiler after the first line will recognize that this struct missing arguments, so they will appear when the same struct used later...

Comment: Case sensitive mismatch: `profile` vs `Profile`

Comment: @vadian, sry for the typo, no it was `profile` but when i posted the question i realize that the `p` is small so i change it to capital letter without updating the screenshot.

Comment: Having the same issue. This worked perfectly before.

Comment: facing same issue.But it works fine for me when you call its init method.Like: ProfileModels.ViewModels.profile().init....

Comment: @Sakshi, i hope so, but sometimes isn't working... check my updated question if the problem is still exist with you even with calling the init method...

Comment: Basically Xcode just sucks and does this a lot. In a huge project, you're lucky when autocomplete works.

Comment: @mojtabaalmoussawi I have just made the test with Xcode 10.1 and it worked perfect. Did you try to update to the latest Xcode version? Regards.

Answer (score 0):

There has been a bug in Xcode for a while where autocompletion for structs would be finicky. Classes have never had this issue, but I was able to fix the autocompletion by typing `.init` after the struct name, triggering the autocompletion, and then deleting the `.init` after. Hope this helps